# Finding minimum mismatch for set of numbers in Python

Tags: python, list, mismatch

I'm attempting to find the minimum mismatch for a data set. I have this set of data in a list that has 40 numbers and I have a k = 1:

```
 list1 = [1, 8, 10, 16, 19, 22, 27, 33, 36, 40, 47, 52, 56, 61, 63, 71, 72, 75, 81, 81, 84, 88, 96, 98, 103, 110, 113, 118, 124, 128, 129, 134, 134, 139, 148, 157, 157, 160, 162, 164]
```

I'm trying to find all the sets of 3 that have the minimum mismatch. Where A <= B <= C and (A-B)^2 defines the mismatch of the set of 3 numbers and it doesn't matter what int C is.

So I first created all the set using the following code and found the difference between all A and B in the results:

```
result = list(zip(list1, list1[1:], list1[2:]))
res = [abs(b - a) for a, b, c in result]
```

Im removing all elements that are greater than the next element in the list res.

```
for i in res:
    if res[i] > res[i+1]:
        res.pop(i)
        result.pop(i)
```

Im trying to get a result like this where there are K + 8 sets in the mismatch list

```
mismatchList = [(8, 10, 16), (19, 22, 27), (61, 63, 75), (71, 72, 88), (81, 81, 84), (96, 98, 103), (128, 129, 148), (134, 134, 139), (157, 157, 160)]
```

Conceptually, Im thinking that I can use recursion to continue to remove each elements in res that are greater than the previous.

Comment: I don't understand your definition of *mismatch*. What is *k*? What is *K*?

Comment: @user04012001 for this given data set K = 1. And I am defining mismatch as the minimum difference between A and B, where A is the first number in the set of 3, B is the second number, and C is the 3rd number. For example, (8, 10, 16), A = 8, B = 10, C = 16. The Mismatch is (A-B)^2 = (8-10)^2 = (-2)^2 = 4. I want to find the minimum mismatch for all set of 3 from list1 and print K + 8 sets from the original list.